# Execute binary file on iOS

Tags: ios, binary, adb

Is there any way to transfer and execute binary files to an iOS device or the iOS Simulator?
I want to port a C-Library to iOS without compiling it with XCode, but with using the cross-compiling feature of [`smake`](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/smake.html). For this purpose it is necessary to gain shell access to the iOS device.
On Android `adb` is making life a lot easier:

```
$ adb push executable /some/path
$ adb shell /some/path/executable
```

Is there something similar for iOS? I am pretty sure, that this is possible on jailbroken iOS-devices, but I am interested in apple-compliant solutions.

Comment: Nope - you'll need to port the library.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with that? Of course I need to port the library since that is what I want to do ;)
Do you mean that there is nothing like `adb` for iOS?

Comment: I mean that you will need to at least re-compile it in order to use it on a different platform. Twice if you want to use it for both the simulator and on an actual iOS device. It sounds from your question like you want to link against an object file from another platform but maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually I wanted to make sure first, whether there even is a possibility to push and execute a compiled binary file, before I deal with the compiling itself.

Comment: OK - I think I see what you want to do, although I'm not sure why. I would guess that this is only going to be possible with a jailbroken iOS device.

Comment: Hm, seems so. But thanks for the help anyway! I'd accept that as an answer to my question!

Comment: Feel free to write it up as an answer and accept it - I'm rep-rich and time-poor today. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently something like this is only possible on jailbroken iOS devices. Since my intention was to do this on a ordinary, apple-compliant way, I will mark this question as answered for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile the app as a module and a C-header, you could import the module into an Xcode project and execute exposed methods from Swift.

But in this scenario you'd be creating a wrapper for the binary with a custom iOS app.